# Matrix form for Delayed Differential Equations(DDEs)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

I have the following system:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \dot{x}_{1} &= -\mu x_{1}(t) + b_{11} x_{3}(t) + b_{12} x_{2}(t-\tau_{1}) \\
    \dot{x}_{1} &= -\mu x_{2}(t) + b_{21} x_{1}(t-\tau_{1}) + b_{22} x_{4}(t) \\
    \dot{x_{3}} &= \mu x_{1}(t-\tau_{1}) - \mu x_{3}(t)\\
    \dot{x_{4}} &= \mu x_{2}(t-\tau_{1}) - \mu x_{4}(t)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

When we try to find its eigenvalues the determinant matrix is written as:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\begin{vmatrix}
     \lambda + \mu & -b_{12} e^{\lambda \tau_{1}} & -b_{11} & 0\\ 
     -b_{21} e^{-\lambda \tau_{1}} & \lambda + \mu & 0 & -b_{22} \\
     -\mu e^{-\lambda \tau_{1}} &  0 & \lambda + \mu & 0 \\
     0 & -\lambda e^{-\lambda \tau_{1}} & 0 & \lambda + \mu \\
\end{vmatrix}
&= 0 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I am wondering why exponential map involved here and what is the matrix of the system exactly other than $det(\lambda I -A)$. I couldn't find an explanation for it. It is probably a very basic thing. Yet, I am struggling to understand it.

Comment: I would assume the exponential comes from making an ansatz on the form of the solutions $x_{i} \propto e^{\lambda t}$, an ansatz that would probably be made due to the system being linear. I'm not sure what you mean by 'what is the matrix of the system exactly', though the matrix itself is simply the coefficients of the system variables. Note that a non-trivial solution exists iff the determinant vanishes which is why the determinant has been set equal to zero.

Comment: This is typical of DDE with discrete delays. Solving for the determinant being zero yields infinitely many roots. This is a sign that that the initial conditions are provided on the interval $[-\tau_1,0]$ instead of just the point $0$ (if considered as initial time).